invalid input syntax for type integer: "{"id":1}" with my delete button
I am getting this invalid input of type integer on my remove button component
The id in the vercel database table is post_id.
Here is my code, I am unsure why I am getting this error
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { HiOutlineTrash } from "react-icons/hi";
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";
export default async function RemoveBtn(id) {
  await sql`DELETE FROM posts01 WHERE post_id =${id}`;
  revalidatePath("/allPosts");
  return (
    <button className="text-red-400 ">
      <HiOutlineTrash size={24} />
    </button>
  );
} ```


All props in the functional component are passed inside the props parameter.
So, you need to change the component definition to the following. (Wrap the id in curly braced.)
export default async function RemoveBtn({ id }) {
  // ...
}

